# How to set values to a Combo Box using ssjs array variable?

Tags: java, arrays, xpages-ssjs

I get values from Db using jdbc and store them in a String Array object. I have a combobox in an xpage and computed its values using ssjs.

The java class has a function,

```
String[] array = new String[20];
    public String[] getName(){
return array;
}
```

The ssjs code is,

```
    var v = new com.vijay.Test1();
var ar = new Array();

for(i=0;i<@count(ar);i++)
ar[i]= "["+v.getName[i]+"]";

return ar;
```

But when previewed, the combobox has no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Vector and not an Array.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. var v = new com.vijay.Test1();
var vec:java.util.Vector=new java.util.Vector();
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
v.addElement(v.name[i]);

return v;

Comment: you have to add to vec and return vec (and not v) :-)

Comment: Oh sorry for that. And Thanks.

Comment: How to do the same with a Bean pal? I have getters and setters for some String array objects. How to get those?